# Driving ban in EU but need to exchange my EU driving licence for UK full license cat B

Tags: driving, exchange, driving-licenses, uk-residents, visa-bans

I have a driving ban in the Czech Republic. Now I live in the UK and need to exchange my driving licence for a UK licence. Will I get a full UK driving licence or not, because of my driving ban in the Czech Republic?

Answer (score 5):

To exchange your Czech (or any foreign license) for a British drivers license, you must fill out DVLA form D1.

That form includes the question “Are you currently disqualified in any other country?”

Lying on this form is a criminal offence.

You are also required to provide your existing license, which will be returned to the Czech issuing authority during the exchange process - its probable that they will also confirm your details and eligibility with the Czech issuing authority at that point as well, and identify your ineligibility at the same time.

Comment: And since people moving to the UK with an EU issued driver's license don't need to replace it, I am not even sure if they can if they wanted to.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo you can - infact, if you want to drive over the age of 70 in the UK you *have* to convert it.  Also, most issuing authorities require you to maintain your current address in that authorities country to continue to hold the license (for example, to hold a UK driving license you must have a valid current UK address, it cannot be a foreign address - if you live elsewhere, you should surrender your UK license).